# Hover is not working properly in windows form Drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

here's my code,

```
        private bool isMouseOverPin(int x, int y, Pin pin)
    {
        int left, top, right, bottom,size;

        size=5;

        left = pin.theRectangle.Left-size;
        right = pin.theRectangle.Right + size;
        top = pin.theRectangle.Top - size;
        bottom = pin.theRectangle.Bottom + size;

        if (x >= left && y >= top && x <= right && y <= bottom)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void pinHover()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pins.Count; i++)
        {
            if (isMouseOverPin(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, pins[i]) == true)
            {
                using (Graphics gr=canvas.CreateGraphics())
                {
                   gr.DrawRectangle(10,10,10,10);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pinHover();
    }
```

i want when some one place a mouse over a pin it draws a rectangle, pin size is 5, i am unable to understand why its not working properly. help plz

Comment: What is `canvas`? BTW .NET uses `gdi+` instead of `gdi`.

Comment: @AlvinWong More accurately, the Graphics class provides access to GDI+, however .NET does also use GDI [for example: TextRenderer.DrawText()].

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your pins location is relative to canvas instead of to screen.

You should pass e.Location from the MouseEventArgs to pinHover, or you could use `PointToClient`

e.g.

```
    List<Int32> DrawPinRects;

    private void initBuffer()
    {
        DrawPinRects = new List<Int32>();
    }

    private void pinHover(Point Position)
    {
        DrawPinRects.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < pins.Count; i++)
        {
            if (isMouseOverPin(Position.X, Position.Y, pins[i]) == true)
            {
                DrawPinRects.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pinHover(e.Location);
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Int32 index in DrawPinRects)
        {
            Int32 y = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value + 10;
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, y, 10, 10);
        }
    }
```

Also this:

```
    int left, top, right, bottom,size;

    size=5;

    left = pin.theRectangle.Left-size;
    right = pin.theRectangle.Right + size;
    top = pin.theRectangle.Top - size;
    bottom = pin.theRectangle.Bottom + size;

    if (x >= left && y >= top && x <= right && y <= bottom)
```

can be simplified to

```
    int size = 5;

    Rectangle TestRect = pin.theRectangle;
    TestRect.Inflate(size,size);

    if (TestRect.Contains(x,y))
```

which will do the same thing.

Comment: its working but when i scroll down or up then it stop working. can you plz tell me wats the reason

Comment: @user1774204 when you scroll the panel? possibly when you move another window over it too... if my guess is correct you need to buffer the `DrawRectangle` and handle it in the `Paint` event instead of in the `MouseMove` event, in the MouseMove event you'd call Invalidate() instead.

Comment: i am already using buffer(bitmap) to draw! but this problem still exists! plz help

Comment: @user1774204 I've made some edit's (haven't tested, so might not compile). You should move the painting code to the paint event on the panel. Having re-read your comment I think you mean that you want the rectangle to stay in that location regardless of scrolling, in which case you need to adjust your rectangle location by the scrolling value. I've also included that. If you have any more questions please ask a new question.